# K6 InfluxDB + Grafana Docker : How to preload a dashboard

Tags: docker, grafana, k6

I am using K6 for Load Testing.

I have cloned the K6, Grafana, InfluxDB docker-compose set up from here:

https://github.com/loadimpact/k6

Each time I start Grafana, I have to manually import the dashboard I want to use ('Import' - ID2587 - Load).

I am new to Docker (and Grafana!)....is there anyway to have this dashboard preloaded in the container so I don't have to manually add it each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mount your dashboard and datasources into grafana container
when running `docker-compose up -d influxdb grafana`
refer the docker-compose file and grafana folder [here](https://github.com/jeevananthank/k6)

And make sure the datasource in your dashboard.json is updated with name of the datasource mentioned in datasource.yml

I have created a small tutorial in k6 [community](https://community.k6.io/t/preload-grafana-dashbaord-with-docker-compose-setup/874). Hope this solves your case.

Answer (score 0):

A few small improvements which I think can help the docker-compose setup be awesome to use:

1. Use the awesome 'k6 Load Testing Results - by dcadwallader' dashboard:
   https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/2587
2. Map a local dashboards directory, as well as the settings for the dashboard with all of the org ids and settings pre-configured, e.g.:

   ```
    volumes:
      - ./dashboards:/var/lib/grafana/dashboards
      - ./grafana-dashboard.yaml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboard.yaml
      - ./grafana-datasource.yaml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yaml
   ```

   https://github.com/luketn/docker-k6-grafana-influxdb/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L32-L35
3. Set the uid in the dashboard JSON file for consistent links, e.g.:

   ```
   {
     uid: "k6",
   ```

   https://github.com/luketn/docker-k6-grafana-influxdb/blob/master/dashboards/k6-load-testing-results_rev3.json#L53

Ref: https://medium.com/swlh/beautiful-load-testing-with-k6-and-docker-compose-4454edb3a2e3

And: https://github.com/luketn/docker-k6-grafana-influxdb