# K6 InfluxDB + Grafana Docker : Which folders and files are actually required and which can be removed?

Tags: docker, k6

I am using K6 for Load Testing, with Grafana and InfluxDB.

I have cloned the K6, Grafana, InfluxDB docker-compose set up from here:

https://github.com/loadimpact/k6

There are a huge number of folders and files in the cloned repository. I am guessing most of them aren't actually needed.

Is there a definitive list showing just the folders/files that are required to run k6, grafana and influxdb so I can clean up my repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you just want the test files.
you just need this [folder](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/tree/master/samples) for running the test scripts using the docker-compose setup

and files for the grafana dashboards and datasources as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63501972/k6-influxdb-grafana-docker-how-to-preload-a-dashboard/63581471#63581471) and the docker-compose.yml

Comment: Thanks Jeevananthan. So what are all the other folders and files for? I thought it was just a docker for running K6 tests with InfluxDB and Grafana.

Comment: @Matt the other files are the full source for building k6. You won't need them to run it as a stack in docker unless you prefer building your own docker image over using the official one. :) If you don't want to run any of the sample scripts, you don't need that directory either.

Comment: Thanks Simme. Yes I have realised now that all you actually need is the docker-compose.yml plus your own stuff.